# Substring with conditional statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, string, t-sql

### tl;dr

I don't understand how to conditionally change the length parameter of `SUBSTRING(..)`

### Short enough, did read

I've got a text field in a sql table that I want to retrieve a substring from

There is a specific part of text I am having trouble retrieving a substring from, because I cannot guarantee the next string.

For example, I have:

```
... Tracking Code : /a/delimited/string   AttributeW : ValueW ...
```

And

```
... Tracking Code : /a/different/delimited/string   A random string ...
```

From both of those i want `/a/delimited/string` and `/a/different/delimited/string` respectively

My current sql looks something like:

```
DECLARE @TrackingStartStr VARCHAR(50), @TrackingEndStr VARCHAR(50)
SET @TrackingStartStr = 'Tracking Code :'
SET @TrackingEndStr = 'Some string that indicates the text is about to end'

SELECT
AField
,RTRIM(LTRIM(Substring(CAST([Body] AS VARCHAR(MAX))
       ,Charindex(@TrackingStartStr,CAST([Body] AS VARCHAR(MAX))) + LEN(@TrackingStartStr)
       ,charindex(@TrackingEndStr,CAST([Body] AS VARCHAR(MAX))) - (Charindex(@TrackingStartStr,CAST([Body] AS VARCHAR(MAX))) + LEN(@TrackingStartStr))
       ))) AS TrackingCode
From tbl_stupidTextTable
```

I don't know how to conditionally change what `@TrackingEndStr` is for each row.

Comment: You should show some examples of strings and what you want to extract from them.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've replaced my examples

Comment: Are the 2 examples you gave each one value on one column?

Comment: I don't really understand the question, and the example is not clear. Can you give some examples of whats in your 'tbl_stupidTextTable' table and what you what to see based on the conditions you define.

Comment: @ShWiVeL Yes, they are.

Comment: @Stuart, the only real information you need is that there is that 'tbl_stupidTextTable' has a TEXT column. It contains text similar to the examples given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select substring(stringfield,
                 charindex('/', stringfield, 1),
                 charindex('   ',
                           stringfield,
                           charindex('/', stringfield, 1)) -
                 charindex('/', stringfield, 1)) as val
  from tbl
```

SQL Fiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cebab/16/0

Comment: Ah sorry, I should have said that in the example `...` means any length string with any characters. However you've really helped because I didnt realise charindex accepted a start location!

Comment: Yes, with that in mind you should be able to get it working if you add on strings to search for that distinguish the start and end of the string. The above works for your example data but it's hard to tell what will work for you (across the whole table) without having a representative sample of the data.